# PostgreSQL Service status Active(Exited) but I am able to connect

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed PostgreSQL (9.5) on a new Ubuntu (16.04) VM on GCD. THe status of service is active(exited). The output of `sudo systemctl status postgresql` is:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-04-14 17:50:34 UTC; 25min ago
  Process: 2291 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2291 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Apr 14 17:50:34 c systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Apr 14 17:50:34 c systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

However the pg_lsclusters shows that a cluster is online.

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

I am also able to login interactively and use psql. There is no error.

I am trying to setup scalelite (https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/scalelite/blob/master/docker-README.md)

When I run

systemctl status scalelite-api.service scalelite-nginx.service

I get following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'scalelite' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Please help me with this and also what does that service status active(exited) mean.

Sorry for incomplete/poor information. I am noob in this domain.

Comment: Solved: https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-get-postgres-to-work/29580/5

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that the server ran out of space. So postgresql could not write data and stopped listening on its port. I removed unused files and restarted PostgreSQL then it worked.

```
cd /
# Check available space
df -hd 1
# delete unused files
find / -type f -name "*unused-file-names*" -delete
# Restart PostgreSQL service
systemctl restart postgresql
```